# How to find any word from source string in target string and remove all matching words from target string in PHP

Tags: php

```
$str_source = "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE";
$str_target = "CLOBETASOL 0.05% CREAM TUBE";
```

Now I want to compare both words of `$str_source` with `$str_target` and then I want to remove matching word(s) from `$str_target`. So my final string after all operations will be `0.05% CREAM TUBE`.

For below case, I am using `str_replace` and it is working fine.

```
$str_source = "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE";
$str_target = "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE 0.05% CREAM TUBE";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare string word count and then explode both and found out diff and then implode it.

```
<?php

$str_source = "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE";
$str_target = "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE 0.05% CREAM TUBE";

if(str_word_count($str_target) >= str_word_count($str_source)){
    echo $finalStringarray = implode(' ',array_diff(explode(' ',$str_target),explode(' ',$str_source)));
}
if(str_word_count($str_source) >= str_word_count($str_target)){
    echo $finalStringarray = implode(' ',array_diff(explode(' ',$str_source),explode(' ',$str_target)));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/p3o8n